# Why does the Brightness button reacting late in Windows 10?

Tags: operating-system, windows-10

I am decreasing or increasing (i.e; Changing) the brightness of my laptop and it's working after a few number of seconds.
Initially it was okay but after a few time it's reacting a bit too late to perform the action (Changing the Brightness level)
Why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen as a result of quite a number of questions :

- The build version of windows you are running on
- Are you a running a windows insider build
- Does your system meet the minimum requires specification to run windows 10
  See here; https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications
- Are your drivers up to date
- Is your windows currently downloading any updates
- Is your windows 10 up to date with the latest stable release build

Comment: When i do restart my system then it gets okay but after few days the problem comes back..